# Dota 2 The International 6 Battle Pass / Compendium Expiration

Tags: dota-2

So it seems like the TI6 compendium **ends 31st Aug 2016**. So my question now is, do we still have `access to our compendium` and `continue to do the quest` **ON 31st Aug 2016**? And the expiration is based on what `timezone`?

Comment: No you cant do the quests anymore. No idea what timezone. I assume its gonna be a timezone in America.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually US time zone PST...yea you'll be able to do this quest till the update comes out. 
Which will disable the quest ..as it is a seasonal event

You may still be able to recycle your immortals to increase your level